# Regex to remove 8 character hash after two + signs

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

`"package_name": "=1.0.0+ea93f6dc",`

I simply want to remove 8 character hash code from this and the + sign `+ea93f6dc`, so that the end result looks like:

`"package_name": "=1.0.0",` (keeping the ",)

I am also find and replacing in Visual Studio so my REGEX looks like this:

`(.*:)(.*)\+([^\+]*)((?="))`

And then I use replace with groups `$1$2$4`

This works, but my method is erroring out when the hash code is not 8 characters long.

Is there any way to signify only find this line if the hash code is 8 characters long?

Also, I feel like I am not doing this in the most efficient way. Ideally I would like to find and replace with an empty string, so I don't have to use groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match an 8 character hash for the example data, you might also use

```
\+[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?=")
```

In the replacement use an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CWcujk/1)

If an infinite length quantifier is supported in the lookbehind, and there have to be at least 2 times a `+` char:

```
(?<=\+[^+]*)\+[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?=")
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `\+[^+]*` Match `+` followed by 0+ times any char except `+`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\+[a-fA-F0-9]{8}` Match `+` and 8 times any of the ranges
- `(?=")` Positive lookahead, assert `"` directy to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XSObjL/1)

Answer (score 4):

This regex matches the "+ and hash" (of any length) you want to "delete":

```
\+[^"]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/zlStxDvaRAEV4i).

Replace (using your undisclosed language/tool) all matches of this regex with the blank string `""` to delete it. eg in java:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\+[^\"]+", "");
```

---

To restrict the length to a range of lengths (unclear if you need this), change `+` (which means "one or more of") to `{n,m}` (which means "from n to m of"), eg for a hash length between 6 and 10 (inclusive):

```
\+[^"]{6,10}
```